# Chrome doesn't refresh static JS file when running local development with Google App Engine Flask dev_appserver.py

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-app-engine, flask

Chrome loads the javascript file, but when I update the file, the update doesn't appear in Chrome. I've tried this in Firefox and I can see that the javascript file has updated when I refresh the page, but not in Chrome.

I'm using Flask and the javascript files are in the static folder. My directory looks like:

```
app
-env
-lib
-static
--css
--img
--js <-- there is where my js file is
-templates
--partials
-app.yaml
-main.py
-requirements.txt
```

My app.yaml file is:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: yes    
# Handlers define how to route requests to your application.
handlers:
# This handler tells app engine how to route requests to a WSGI application.
# The script value is in the format <path.to.module>.<wsgi_application>
# where <wsgi_application> is a WSGI application object.
- url: .*  # This regex directs all routes to main.app
  script: main.app
```

Comment: Did you try disabling cache in chrome dev tools (Ctrl + Shift + i)?  Network tab at the top the checkbox for disabling cache.  The dev tools window has to be open for any of the options to work.

Comment: whoa, yes, thank you @Derek, that totally worked! You should answer this as an official answer!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl + Shift + i    Network Tab > Disable cache.

Note: Dev tools has to be open for options to work.

Answer (score 0):

You may keep you code under flask under yourapp/static/js as mentioned in 
http://exploreflask.com/en/latest/static.html

use versions in javascript when you modify it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/demo.js?v=17"></script>
```